# is it possible to use value converters for window properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I would like to bind value for Top and Left properties of a window. I need to use valueconverter and valueconverterparameter (to be precise: I need a datacontext of my window), unfortunatelly I am getting error that my value converter has not been found.

```
<Window x:Class="Proofing_Tool.wwwww"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Proofing_Tool"
        xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Proofing_Tool.ValueConverters"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="180"
        MinHeight="50" 
        Width="340"  
        SizeToContent="Height" 
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        WindowStyle="None" 
        Background="{x:Null}"     
        OpacityMask="White"  
        Name="AnomalyWindow"
        Title="Anomaly Details"
        ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        Left="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ValueConverterAnomalyToLeft},ConverterParameter={x:Reference Name=AnomalyWindow}}" 
        Top="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ValueConverterAnomalyToTop},ConverterParameter={x:Reference Name=AnomalyWindow}}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <conv:ValueConverterAnomalyToLeft x:Key="ValueConverterAnomalyToLeft" />
        <conv:ValueConverterAnomalyToTop x:Key="ValueConverterAnomalyToTop" />
</Window.Resources>
```

EDIT, issue with updating values, below part works well:

```
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding  Ano.Name, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

code behind:

```
public  Anomaly Ano
{
    get { return _ano; }
    set
    {
        _ano = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

That is updated only once:

Comment: Move the resource declarations to Application.Resources in App.xaml. In order to pass the Window's DataContext to the converter, use a MultiBinding with a MultiValueConverter, where one of the child Bindings is just `<Binding/>`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I am hosting WPF controls inside VSTO/Winforms app so I am not able to put declarations inside App.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...unfortunatelly I am getting error that my value converter has not been found.

That's because the resources are created *after* the `Left` and `Top` properties are set.

You can fix this by using element syntax to bind to the properties after the resources have been created:

```
<Window x:Class="Proofing_Tool.wwwww"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Proofing_Tool"
    xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Proofing_Tool.ValueConverters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="180"
    MinHeight="50" 
    Width="340"  
    SizeToContent="Height" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    WindowStyle="None" 
    Background="{x:Null}"     
    OpacityMask="White"  
    Name="AnomalyWindow"
    Title="Anomaly Details"
    ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.Resources>
        <conv:ValueConverterAnomalyToLeft x:Key="ValueConverterAnomalyToLeft" />
        <conv:ValueConverterAnomalyToTop x:Key="ValueConverterAnomalyToTop" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Left>
        <Binding Path="." Converter="{StaticResource ValueConverterAnomalyToLeft}" ConverterParameter="{x:Reference Name=AnomalyWindow}" />
    </Window.Left>
    <Window.Top>
        <Binding Path="." Converter="{StaticResource ValueConverterAnomalyToTop}" ConverterParameter="{x:Reference Name=AnomalyWindow}" />
    </Window.Top>
</Window>
```

The order matters. The other option would be to define the resources in `App.xaml`.

Comment: Thanks, it works partially (I needed to remove reference to AnomalyWindow) , but there is problem with updating value, it updates value only once. I am using now Path ="Ano" instead of using Path=".", but with "." it didn't work as well. From the other hand I have also binded value to that property and it updated value of textblock every time Ano value is changed. I will add that code to the root post.

Comment: Did you try to set the Mode property of the binding to TwoWay and raise the PropertyChanged event for the data-bound source property?

Comment: I have not set earlier TwoWay mode, because, at least in theory I did not need it, and one way mode worked well in another control that is binded to the same property. BUT, from some weird reason it seems that TwoWay mode works well and values are updated every time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.thejoyofcode.com/WPF_Quick_Tip_Converters_as_MarkupExtensions.aspx

if you look at the V3 section of that post, you find a nice simple elegant solution for this, which allows you to do what you want like this:

```
Top="{Binding ., Converter={local:MyTopConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference Name=AnomalyWindow}}"
```

no need to define it inside .Resources anywhere at all.